# Order an ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a user object with a collection of email. I want to return the last registered address. To do this I made a DataTable, run Select and ordered on date, but is they're any other way of doing this directly with the collection?

So basically what I want is that the address at [0] position is the last registered. Can I achieve this with ICollection or should I use something else?

**User**:

```
public ICollection<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; } = new HashSet<EmailAddress>();
```

**EmailAddress**:

```
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public DateTime DateLastInvoked { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public int LastInvokedByClientId { get; set; }
```

**Solution**:

```
EmailAddress result = this.EmailAddresses.Where(adr => adr.Active.Equals(true)).OrderByDescending(dt => dt.DateCreated).First();
```

Answer (score 8):

Look up [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). There are more basic linq query operations.

```
using System.Linq;

EmailAddresses = EmailAddresses.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated).ToList();
```

This will order your collection in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the last registered address, you'd sort the list then use [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
var lastRegisteredAddress = EmailAddresses.OrderByDescending( a => a.DateCreated ).First();
```

Comment: but how do I use OrderByDescending directly with a List? When I need to sort the list it's available as List<EmailAddress>

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable` so you can use the `OrderByDescending` extension method on it. You just need to add `using System.Linq` to the top.